# Members of group can't access directory in linux

Tags: linux, file-permissions, access-control, user-permissions, usergroups

I was trying to create two directories `assignment` and `exam_papers` containing assignment and question paper text files inside them respectively. After that, I created two users `vipin` , `booma`.Then added `vipin` to `teacher` group and `booma` to `student` group respectively.

[image: Look at this screenshot for specification]

**Idea**

The idea is I wanted to set permissions for `assignment` and `exam_papers` directory like only members of the `teacher` group can *read write* to the `assignment` and `exam_paper` directory and members of `student` and other users can only read the content of `assignment` directory

[image]

Here You can see that I removed all permissions from other users for `exam_paper` directory and gives only *Read* permission to other users for `assignment` directory.

Motive of this is, members of `student` group and other users can't access the `exam_paper` directory and can access `assignment` directory with only *Read* permission

**Result**

The result of all this is that even members of `teacher` group can't access both of these directories

Comment: I think this question suits better to other StackExchange networks, like https://superuser.com/. You may get better and faster answers there, as this is kind of OS-based question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directories require executable access to enter/see contents. So if you wanted a group to have access privileges to a directory `chmod -R 775 assignment/` should work.